# Using Fake SMTP Server to read sent emails on localhost for Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, smtp, xampp

I am using WooCommerce with Wordpress and I want to view the emails that get sent out when an order is complete on my localhost development environment.
I have the program Fake SMTP Server setup to listen at port 25 but no email appears to arrive within the app?

Any ideas what this could be - I am using a recent installation of XAMPP

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Mailnest.io should work for you

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why Fake SMTP wouldn't be working for you. Might I suggest giving [MailSlurper](http://mailslurper.com) a try. Local mail server, web-based interface. *Full disclosure - I am the author of MailSlurper.*

Answer (score -2):

For anyone else looking to use test email in WordPress please take a look at [Imitate Email](https://imitate.email) (it is one of my projects).

Free to get going, tested with WordPress and a 1 line JS will drop it in to your WordPress site so that you can see test emails as you work on WordPress.